# Add snowfall effect to image/video using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-editing

Has anyone thought of creating snowfall effect on a video using OpenCV? If so, do you have any idea regarding the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as a sketch to give an idea :)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::default_random_engine generator(time(NULL));
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution_bin;
void getGradient(Mat& src, Mat& mag, Mat& ang)
{
    Mat src_g;
    cvtColor(src, src_g, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    src_g.convertTo(src_g, CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    GaussianBlur(src_g, src_g, Size(3, 3), 2);
    Mat gx, gy;
    Sobel(src_g, gx, -1, 1, 0);
    Sobel(src_g, gy, -1, 0, 1);
    magnitude(gx, gy, mag);
    phase(gx, gy, ang, true);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class snow
{
public:
    float threshold;
    float x;
    float y;
    float t;
    float phase;
    bool dead;
    snow()
    {
        threshold = 0.5;
        x = distribution(generator);
        phase = distribution(generator);
        y = 0;
        dead = false;
    }

    void step(Mat& canvas, Mat& res_dead, Mat& mag, Mat& ang)
    {
        if(x<1)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        if (x>canvas.cols-2)
        {
            x = canvas.cols-2;
        }

        float g = mag.at<float>(y+1, x);
        float a = ang.at<float>(y+1, x);

        float rdL = res_dead.at<Vec3b>(y + 1, x-1)[0];
        float rdM = res_dead.at<Vec3b>(y + 1, x)[0];
        float rdR = res_dead.at<Vec3b>(y + 1, x+1)[0];

        if (rdL >0  && rdM > 0 && rdR == 0)
        {
            g = 10;
            a = 20;
        }
        if (rdL == 0 && rdM > 0 && rdR > 0)
        {
            g = 10;
            a = 140;
        }
        if (rdL > 0 && rdM > 0 && rdR > 0)
        {
            dead = true;
            return;
        }
        if (rdL == 0 && rdM > 0 && rdR == 0)
        {
            int des= distribution_bin(generator);
            if (des == 0)
            {
                a = 20;
            }
            else
            {
                a = 140;
            }
        }

        if (g < threshold && rdM==0)
        {
            ++y;
            x += 1 * sin(t/10+phase);
        }
        ++t;
        if (g > threshold)
        {
            if (a < 45 && a > 10)
            {
                ++y;
                ++x;
            }else if (a > 135 && a < 170)
            {
                ++y;
                --x;
            }
            else
            {
                ++y;
                dead = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (x > mag.cols - 1)
        {
           // ++y;
            x = mag.cols - 2;
            dead = true;
            return;
        }
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            dead = true;
            return;
        }
        if (y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
            dead = true;
            return;
        }
        if (y >= mag.rows - 1)
        {
            y = mag.rows - 1;
            dead = true;
            return;
        }
    }
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, unsigned int** argv)
{

    Mat src=imread("F:/ImagesForTest/lena.jpg",1);
    Mat res = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
    Mat res_dead = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
    distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,src.cols-1);
    distribution_bin = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 1);
    Mat mag, ang;
    Mat mag_s= Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat ang_s = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_32FC1);

    Mat mag_sum, ang_sum;

    getGradient(src, mag, ang);

    vector<snow> s(100);
    int key = 0;
    while(key!=27)
    {

        mag_sum = mag + mag_s;
        ang_sum = ang + ang_s;

        for (int k = 0; k < 20; ++k)
        {
            snow sn;
            s.push_back(sn);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); ++j)
        {
            s[j].step(res, res_dead, mag_sum, ang_sum);
            if (s[j].y < 0)
            {
                s[j].y = 0;
            }
            res.at<Vec3b>(s[j].y, s[j].x) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
            if (s[j].dead)
            {
                res_dead.at<Vec3b>(s[j].y, s[j].x) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
                s.erase(s.begin() + j);
            }
        }
        res += res_dead;
        imshow("res", res+src);
        key=waitKey(10);
        res = 0;
    }
    imshow("src", src);
    key=waitKey(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Checking out this answer after a long time.